# IEqualityComparer with Linq to XML and Distinct() is not executed in code?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, distinct, iequalitycomparer

It doesnt matter what I write in the Equals method. The GetHashCode is always fired, but I do not know whose GetHashCode to return?

When the GetHashCode method is called then variable x has the following data:

In the first unitName elementName is the value "This is the value I want to compare" ...

```
<unit>
  <unitName>This is the value I want to compare</unitName>
  <units>
    <unit>
      <unitName>xxx</unitName>      
      <units>
        <unit>
          <unitName>cccc</unitName>
          <test>33</test>
          <test>44</test>                   
        </unit>
      </units>          
        </unit>
    </units>        
</unit>
```

```
IEnumerable<XElement> tempMemberList = doc.Elements("dep").Descendants("customers").Distinct(new XElementComparer());

public class XElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement> {
    public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y) {

        return x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement x) {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution, I just had to get the proper value from the first unitName I wanted...

```
public class XElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
        {
            public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
            {
                string unitNameX = x.Element("unitName ").Value;
                string unitNameY = y.Element("unitName ").Value;
                return unitNameX == unitName Y;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(XElement x)
            {
                string val = x.Element("unitName ").Value;
                return val.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense to return the hash code of the `Value` of the element as you are using that to determine equality.  Your `GetHashCode()` implementation must be consistent with your `Equals()` implementation.

```
public class XElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement> {
    public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y) {
        return x.Value == y.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement x) {
        return x.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: p.s., Your query doesn't actually yield any elements.  There aren't any `dep` elements nor are there `customers` elements in your posted XML.

Comment: Well sure that's fine, but if you're going to change the names, you should be consistent and change all its uses so you don't break anything.  ;)

Comment: As you knew my xml structure you should have used "unitName" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write something which will work for most of xml.

```
public class XElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y) 
    {
        return (x.FirstAttribute.Value.Equals(y.FirstAttribute.Value) 
                && x.LastAttribute.Value.Equals(y.LastAttribute.Value)); 
    } 

    public int GetHashCode(XElement x) 
    { 
        return x.Value.GetHashCode(); 
    }
}
```